# PERL Unicode Escape string pass from command line argument wrong output

Tags: perl, unicode, escaping

Here is my perl code:

```
use Unicode::Escape;

my $string = shift;
print Unicode::Escape::escape($string) . "\n";
```

When I execute this script from terminal the unicode is not escape

perl unicode_escape.pl "https://docs.google.com/uc?id\u003d0ByPZe438mUkZVkNfTHZLejFLcnc\u0026export\u003ddownload\u0026revid\u003d0ByPZe438mUkZbUIxRkYvM2dwbVduRUxSVXNERm0zZFFiU2c0PQ"

**Output:**

```
https://docs.google.com/uc?id\u003d0ByPZe438mUkZVkNfTHZLejFLcnc\u0026export\u003ddownload\u0026revid\u003d0ByPZe438mUkZbUIxRkYvM2dwbVduRUxSVXNERm0zZFFiU2c0PQ
```

But when the string is inside the code

```
use Unicode::Escape;

my $string = "https://docs.google.com/uc?id\u003d0ByPZe438mUkZVkNfTHZLejFLcnc\u0026export\u003ddownload\u0026revid\u003d0ByPZe438mUkZbUIxRkYvM2dwbVduRUxSVXNERm0zZFFiU2c0PQ";

print Unicode::Escape::escape($string) . "\n";
```

when I execute the script

```
perl unicode_escape.pl
```

It produces the correct output

**Output**

```
https://docs.google.com/uc?id003d0ByPZe438mUkZVkNfTHZLejFLcnc0026export003ddownload0026revid003d0ByPZe438mUkZbUIxRkYvM2dwbVduRUxSVXNERm0zZFFiU2c0PQ
```

I don't understand how perl decides to do this? Please help

**UPDATE:**

Hi, ikegami
I tried this but still does not work here is my code:

```
use Unicode::Escape;

my $string = shift;

$string =~ s/\\/\\\\/g;

print Unicode::Escape::escape($string) . "\n";
```

I am trying to produce the output the same as the 2nd code snippet.

What I want to do is when I run this command just like in the 1st code snippet.

```
perl unicode_escape.pl "https://docs.google.com/uc?id\u003d0ByPZe438mUkZVkNfTHZLejFLcnc\u0026export\u003ddownload\u0026revid\u003d0ByPZe438mUkZbUIxRkYvM2dwbVduRUxSVXNERm0zZFFiU2c0PQ"
```

It should give the output the same as the 2nd code snippet

**Output**

```
https://docs.google.com/uc?id003d0ByPZe438mUkZVkNfTHZLejFLcnc0026export003ddownload0026revid003d0ByPZe438mUkZbUIxRkYvM2dwbVduRUxSVXNERm0zZFFiU2c0PQ
```

Comment: In the 1st example, `$string` contains whatever your shell passes into the program as the 1st argument.  In the 2nd example, `$string` contains the result of double quote interpolation as defined in `perldoc perlop`.  Printing the "unescaped" version of the string may prove informative.  Finally, I see no non-ASCII characters in your strings that require escaping.

Answer (score 0):

In the first snippet, you assign the following to `$string`:

```
https://docs.google.com/...download\u0026revid...
```

In the second snippet, you assign the following to `$string`:

```
https://docs.google.com/...download0026revid...
```

In a Perl double-quoted string literal, `\u` causes the next character to be uppercased. You need to escape `\`.

```
my $string = "https://docs.google.com/...download\\u0026revid...";
```